# What is the most efficient way to query multiple tables using a distinct column from each table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write an efficient query to pull multiple columns each from different tables. Each of the 5 tables are very large; my current query works but takes over 2 minutes using only 50 combinations of Account #s and codes. I need the query to return 3 columns, each from different tables using conditions from multiple tables.

This is the current query:

```
select table1.Name, table3.Account, table5.Code

from  db_table1 table1, db_table2 table2,
      db_table3 table3, db_table4 table4, db_table5 table5

where  table1.Name     = table2.Name     and 
       table2.ID       = 16              and
       table2.PhoneNum = table3.PhoneNum and
       table3.Account  = table4.Account  and 
       table4.Zip      = table5.Zip      and 
     ((table3.Account  = 1234567 and table5.Code = 'abcd') or
      (table3.Account  = 2345678 and table5.Code = 'bcde') or
      (table3.Account  = 3456789 and table5.Code = 'cdef'));
```

Basically, I have a list of Account #s and Codes and need to see which rows have a name associated with a combination of the two. I also only want rows where table2's ID = 16. The 3 columns I need to retrieve are all from different tables - and since those 3 tables do not share a common column, I am forced to join across multiple other tables.

edit: This is a corporate database. Certain statements are restricted from executing, such as delete, create, alter, and drop.

Thank you!

Comment: `OR` tends to negate indexing benefits; if your query is that slow I would suggest UNIONing near identical queries (each with one of the different OR conditions), and making sure `table3.Account` and `table5.Code` are indexed fields. ...and of course (and firstly) make sure the joining fields are indexed appropriately.  ...Edit: Also, try to use actual JOIN syntax, the "list of tables" syntax has been out of favor for close to two decades.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  You'll probably find that some of your join conditions are incomplete.

Comment: @Uueerdo, Thanks for your reply! See my edit - This is a corporate database. Certain statements are restricted from executing such as create so I don't believe I can index. Can you please explain what you mean by UNIONing near identical queries? I rarely use UNION and am not sure how to apply it here. Edit: Also, is there a performance difference when using the "list of tables" syntax compared to JOIN syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit of explicit join syntax is readability, it makes actual joins versus intentional cross products more obvious and keeps join criteria relatively close to the tables being joined.

As far as actual speed, the query optimizer usually seems to do a good job of sorting things out so it doesn't usually hurt you either way there (other than not being able to take advantage of query modifiers like `STRAIGHT_JOIN` that allow you to force order of operations in the situations where the optimizer does make bad choices.)

For example, to me and many others this is a much more readable version of your query:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t3.Account, t5.Code
FROM db_table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN db_table2 AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
INNER JOIN db_table3 AS t3 ON t2.PhoneNum = t3.PhoneNum
INNER JOIN db_table4 AS t4 ON t3.Account = t4.Account
INNER JOIN db_table5 AS t5 ON t4.Zip = t5.Zip
WHERE t2.ID = 16 
 AND 
 ((t3.Account = 1234567 AND t5.Code = 'abcd')
   OR (t3.Account = 2345678 AND t5.Code = 'bcde')
   OR (t3.Account = 3456789 AND t5.Code = 'cdef')
 )
;
```

---

The UNION technique I was talking about would convert the above query to this:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t3.Account, t5.Code
FROM db_table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN db_table2 AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
INNER JOIN db_table3 AS t3 ON t2.PhoneNum = t3.PhoneNum
INNER JOIN db_table4 AS t4 ON t3.Account = t4.Account
INNER JOIN db_table5 AS t5 ON t4.Zip = t5.Zip
WHERE t2.ID = 16 AND t3.Account = 1234567 AND t5.Code = 'abcd'
UNION
SELECT t1.Name, t3.Account, t5.Code
FROM db_table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN db_table2 AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
INNER JOIN db_table3 AS t3 ON t2.PhoneNum = t3.PhoneNum
INNER JOIN db_table4 AS t4 ON t3.Account = t4.Account
INNER JOIN db_table5 AS t5 ON t4.Zip = t5.Zip
WHERE t2.ID = 16 AND t3.Account = 2345678 AND t5.Code = 'bcde'
UNION
SELECT t1.Name, t3.Account, t5.Code
FROM db_table1 AS 1
INNER JOIN db_table2 AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
INNER JOIN db_table3 AS t3 ON t2.PhoneNum = t3.PhoneNum
INNER JOIN db_table4 AS t4 ON t3.Account = t4.Account
INNER JOIN db_table5 AS t5 ON t4.Zip = t5.Zip
WHERE t2.ID = 16 AND t3.Account = 3456789 AND t5.Code = 'cdef'
;
```

`OR` usually leaves MySQL unable to take advantage of indexes, doing it this way makes the (effectively) multiple queries simpler and can allow the indexes to be taken advantage of once again. *However, doing this kind of thing before you need to unless you are fairly certain the technique will be needed (familiar pattern on a growing table) is not something I recommend, in many cases running more queries (which is what this kind of does) is not the best solution.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! If I understand correctly, using INNER JOIN is not necessarily faster/more efficient, but more preferred for readability. Using the UNION technique, I can take advantage of indexing and possibly improve performance. However, I have 281K combinations of Account # and code I need to check for. This is being queried on a production database - and you mentioned that this is not something you recommend. Are there potential impacts or issues that could arise when querying the database with this method?

Comment: Oh, not just the three OR cases you presented? Then this really isn't applicable. 281k combinations sounds like they must come from the database itself; if there is a query you are using to retrieve those combinations, you should probably include it in the question.

Comment: the 281k combination comes from a database report on an upstream system that I do not have access rights to. An excel file was sent to me with a 281k row list of 'Account' and 'Code' combinations. Those fields from the other system are present in our system as well, and thus we are able to use them to find any associated 'Name'. The current query is taking roughly an hour per 40k, so this will take hours to complete any time I need to run it - hence why I am trying to optimize it.